# within five meaning

Tags: idioms

I am watching "Man seeking Woman season 1 - episode 1 in 0 min ~ 5 min"

I copied part of the dialog below.

> Mike was using Finding Sex Partner app.
>
> Josh : Does that thing actually work?
>   Mike : Where is Cermak?
>   Josh : It's, like, eight blocks away.
>   Mike : I can usually get it **within five**. Your place is remote, man.
>             You got to get on this thing, bro.
>              I mean, it's just weird to think about being with anybody else --
>              we were together for six years.

I don't understand what "within five" means and why he said "your place is remote."

Comment: within five minutes

Answer (score 1):

Probably "I can usually get it within five" is just a shorthand way of saying "I can usually get there within five minutes." (For example, "I can usually walk there in five minutes.")

By "your place is remote," Mike seems to be saying to Josh that the place where Josh lives is far away from wherever they are talking about going. (So while it only takes Mike five minutes to get there, it might take Josh 30 minutes or an hour to get there, for example, maybe.)

Comment: If five=5 minuate, I think that means he usually fuck a girl like that within five minuate.

and "your place is remote.", I think there is something other meaning more than literal meaning.

I'm so sorry not to explain the scene clearly. If you watch the video, you would understand me. haha. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

He's saying that usually when he uses this app he finds a girl within five blocks. But since he's at his friend's house, the only available girls are a whole eight blocks away, which is why he considers the house "remote".

Comment: Ty. I understand.